# Javascript turning object map into Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript

Say for example I had an object map of the following:

```
{
    "key1" : { data: "data1", extra: "none" },
    "key2" : { data: "data2", extra: "none" },
    "key3" : { data: "data3", extra: "none" },
    "key4" : { data: "data4", extra: "none" }, 
};
```

Is there a convenient way to convert it to a multidimesional array something like this:

```
[
    [ "key1" , { data: "data1", extra: "none" } ],
    [ "key2" , { data: "data2", extra: "none" } ],
    [ "key3" , { data: "data3", extra: "none" } ],
    [ "key4" , { data: "data4", extra: "none" } ], 
];
```

I have a function that requires an array, yet the data I'm receiving from a 3rd party plugin is in object arrays. It would be nice if there was some simple way to get the conversion done between the two.

Comment: Have you tried: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: note that the order of `key1`..`key4` is not defined in the original array.

Comment: @Floradu88 I don't quite understand how this could be a duplicate question. I'm asking how I'd go about converting from an object map, not an array.

Comment: @dk123 removed the comment.

Comment: @Floradu88 Thanks. It would have been nice if those other people that voted for this thread to be closed to have at least left an explanation;

Comment: In ES6 you can just do: `Object.entries(obj)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function convert(original) {
    var multiArray = [];
    for(var key in original) { multiArray.push([ key, original[key] ]); }
    return multiArray;
}
```

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/633Bw/4/)**.

Use it like this:

```
var myObject = {
    "key1" : { data: "data1", extra: "none" },
    "key2" : { data: "data2", extra: "none" },
    "key3" : { data: "data3", extra: "none" },
    "key4" : { data: "data4", extra: "none" }, 
};
var myMultiArray = convert(myObject);
```

Comment: You could just use `for (var i in original)`, since `for ... in` is for object keys.

Comment: @JanDvorak you are right, I overlooked it. Just improved. Thanks!

Comment: Better now :-) Note that you're still assuming that noone has extended `Object.prototype` (but that's a safe assumption to make).

Comment: @JanDvorak Curious. In the current code? Where am I making that assumption, exactly?

Comment: @acdcjunior when you do `for(i in x)`, it iterates over _all_ enumerable properties of `x`, including those in the prototype chain. When you do `Object.prototype.bind = function(){...}`, every object has an enumerable property called `bind`, that this loop will return. When you do it, you break jQuery, too.

Comment: @JanDvorak alright, I think I got it (I had to google it a bit, I admit). Thanks again, that's high level knowledge!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've chosen this as my accepted answer as it 1. works across all major browsers, 2. easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you make a helper function `pair` like below, then the standard keys/map is good enough:

```
Object.keys(m).map(pair.bind(m))
function pair(x){return [x, this[x]]}
```

Comment: elegant and succinct.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with JS; I don't quite understand how I'd go about using this. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @dk123 the first line is the usage.

Comment: @JanDvorak What's the 'm'?

Comment: @dk123 that's the original `m`ap.

Comment: Bind -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
Object.keys -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
Map -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: So this basically replaces the original `m`ap with the newly edited values?

Comment: @dk123 not _replaces_, _evaluates to_. Ex: `output = Object.keys(input).map(pair.bind(input))`. Note the second line is supposed to be somewhere in the header

Comment: +1 @JanDvorak Thank you for the explanation, it's made things clear.

Comment: @dk123 `bind` won't work in old IE unless polyfilled. acdcjunior's answer will work everywhere.

Comment: +1 @JanDvorak Thanks for the info. Deleted last comment and finalized accepted answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply, I really like the simplicity of this. I went with acdcjunior's answer though because of it's functionality across all major browsers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 it's as easy as `[[e, o[e]] for (e in o)]`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this really looks amazing. I chose geocar's answer in the end due to current lack of general support for ES6. Great answer though, it really makes me look forward to the capabilities of what's coming!

Comment: @neil This fails in 2017 (chromium/firefox). Are you sure it‘s going to work like this?

Comment: @undko Sadly it was only a proposal and didn't make ES6 in the end. The latest proposal is `[...Object.entries(o)]` which I think works in current Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: @neil Thanks! A bit more verbose, but still a big improvement compared to loops :-)